# How to apply a function if conditon a & b

Tags: conditional-tags

I want to apply a function if post is updated and if post author id is not 1.
For this i tried many functions like

```
<?php if (get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time()) && ( $author_id != 1 ) : ?>
```

By this code **if post is updated** is working but **if post author is not 1** not working.
Please help me!

Comment: `$author_id` is undefined in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i find answer.
The perfect code is

```
<?php $author_id = $post->post_author; if (get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() && ( $author_id != 1 )): ?>
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

With a global *$post* object you could check the conditions also like this:

```
global $post;
if ( $post->post_date != $post->post_modified && $post->post_author != 1 ) :
    // your code
endif;
```

But if you prefer to use just functions then you can do this:

```
if ( get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() && get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) != 1 ) :
    // your code
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<?php if (get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() && ( $author_id != 1 )): ?>
```

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: Code only answers are usually marked as "Low Quality". Could you expand on your answer and explain how this is a solution to the current problem?